# I can not remove the package burg

Tags: burg

I can not remove the package burg and console show me errors:

```
 root@iskander-des:~# sudo apt-get autoremove burg
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет «burg» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакеты, которые будут УДАЛЕНЫ:
  burg-theme-dark-shine
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 1 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 1 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства уменьшится на 1 720 kB.
Хотите продолжить [Д/н]? Y
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 299082 файла и каталога.)
Удаляется пакет burg-theme-dark-shine …
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке параметра burg-theme-dark-shine (--remove):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-removal возвратил код ошибки 1
Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                                                   При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 burg-theme-dark-shine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the `/boot/burg/locale` file is missing. Create it manually with:

```
sudo touch /boot/burg/locale
```

After that you will be able to remove the package.